# Make spring boot return 406 instead of 415 with RequestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**** EDIT ****

Upon feedback, i am attaching the following disclaimer:

I ***KNOW*** that 415 is the normal code and i ***KNOW*** the normal conditions that cause it... The API i am implementing specifies this override for some reason and I cant change it because I don't control it

**** END EDIT ****

So I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, path = "/foo", 
                consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Something> postFoo() {
    return null;
}
```

When I post a message without the `Content-Type` header set, I get the expected 415, but I want to change that to return 406 without any boilerplate code. Is that possible? I've searched and searched, but I cant seem to find any docs telling me how to do this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that (considering @marthursson's explanations below)?

Comment: @nterry -- have you tried my solution by any chance and it didn't work?

Comment: @Deroude Ill give it a try tomorrow, but looking at it; it seems that its what I wanted. I suspected it would be a ControllerAdvice, but I couldn't find what to override to change the behaviour

Answer (score -2):

415 is the appropriate response status when the specified "Content-Type" header is not supported by the target service. 406 means "Not acceptable", which should be returned only when an invalid (or missing) "Accept" header is supplied.

The behaviour you are seeing is correct, and you shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question is probably based on a misunderstanding. My answer clarifies the meaning of the error codes. Changing status codes based on a personal opinion of what they should be (as opposed to the standard) is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Deroude As marthursson said, the question is based on a misunderstanding from HTTP status code meanings. And this is the correct answer!

Comment: That is your personal opinion. The guy said he gets "the expected 415", so he knows what it means. You haven't answered the question, nor really helped anyone. There are plenty of production situations where you want to override the HTTP status code semantics, fully aware of what you are doing. When I ask such a question, I usually post a disclaimer saying that I fully understand what it means, to prevent precisely such answers.

Comment: Status code semantics is a standard, not a matter of opinion. Changing these semantics is a slippery slope to confusion. Error statuses indicate to the client what can be changed in order for the server to accept the request. A 406 status clearly states to the client that supplying a correct Accept header will fix the problem, which is obviously not true in this case.

Comment: " obviously not true in this case" -- ok, how do you know that? Maybe both 415 and 406 are applicable to that request and you would just like to prioritize 406 over 415. Maybe you have a client provided, which you cannot change, that fails your HTTP Bible and goes to Standard Hell, but until it does, you need to supply precisely those codes IT understands. So, assuming for just a second that the guy actually knows what he is doing, do you have a solution for him?

Comment: @marthursson I understand the codes and their meanings. The API contract I am implementing requires a 406. Regardless of the reasons why, an 'answer' should actually answer the question, not pontificate on the validity of the question...

Answer (score -3):

Would you consider `return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)` boilerplate?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the clarification: the exception is thrown by Spring when processing the request, before entering your handler method. So, what you can do is change the default behavior for that particular exception. To do that, create your own [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html), overriding that specific method, like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalWebExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        /* other processing */
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/#controlleradvice) is an excellent article covering this.

Comment: The default error returned based on missing Accept/Content-Type headers is handled automatically by the framework before the method is called, so there's no convenient way of handling this in the method body (unless you don't specify 'consumes' and 'produces' in the annotation, which you really shouldn't do).